# Iframe content load in Chrome browser

Tags: ajax, selenium, google-chrome, iframe

I am trying to launch my application which loads iframe as soon as url completely gets loaded.

The iframe has 3 fields:

- username,
- password
- next button.

When I pass the details and click on the next button, it should load otp content (*ajax call*) in the same iframe,  when I use chrome I can pass a username and password, but upon clicking on next button, it's going to some private site instead of loading the otp content in the same iframe, whereas things are working fine in IE browser. I am not getting any exception also.

What could be the reason?